# Swift 2: dictionary of closures array

Tags: swift

I need to define dictionary of strings as keys with arrays of closures as values. Sample structure:

```
{
    "url1 hash": [loadHandler1, loadHandler2],
    "url2 hash": [loadHandler1],
    "url3 hash": [loadHandler1, loadHandler2, loadHandler3],    
    ...
}
```

Load handler is simple closure: `() -> NSData?`

This code compiles without errors

```
let test1: [String: [String]] = [String: [String]]()

typealias Handler = () -> NSData? //workaround
let test2: [String: [Handler]] = [String: [Handler]]()

let test3: [() -> NSData?] = []
```

but

```
let test4: [String: [() -> NSData?]] = [String: [() -> NSData?]]()
```

gives "Expected ',' separator" after '()' and "Expected expression in container literal"

```
let test5: [String: [() -> NSData?]] = [String: []]()
```

gives "Type expression is ambiguous without more context"

Why I'm getting an error in last two examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `test4` you get that error because `()` alone is a complete type: the empty tuple aka `Void`, to state that the type is `() -> NSData?` you can use parenthesis as

```
let test4: [String: [(() -> NSData?)]] = [String: [(() -> NSData?)]]()
```

or better your `typealias`.

The error you get in `test5` is a direct effect of the same error you get in `test4`: since the compiler cannot understand correctly the type of your variable it cannot infer the type of the array (`[]`) you want to create and assign to `test5`.

**UPDATE:** after some tests with a playground I've found that that the compiler has some problem understanding closures types when creating an array/dictionary but it's fine with the same declaration used for the type. The compiler is fine with

```
let test3: [() -> NSData?] = []
let test4: [String: [() -> NSData?]] = [:]
```

but if we don't declare the type and let it infer it from the array/dictionary we assign to the variable it's stuck and this won't compile:

```
let test3 = [() -> NSData?]()
let test4 = [String: [() -> NSData?]]()
```

and even wrapping the signature of the closure in parenthesis won't work. I think it's a bug, you should file a report.

Comment: "`()` alone is a complete type" - but why I don't get same error in `test3`?

Comment: I've just done some tests in a playground and found out no valid reason for that, it seems that the compiler has a problem creating the array/dictionary but can understand correctly when declaring the type. Let me update the answer with more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I'll report this issue